# action item's icon is not showing

Tags: android

Here is *menu xml* file.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
         android:title="@string/action_create_order"
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_shopping_cart_black_36dp"
         android:orderInCategory="1"
         app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
         android:title="@string/action_share"
         android:orderInCategory="2"
         app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
         android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
         android:title="@string/action_settings"
         android:orderInCategory="100"
         app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Here is my `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method

```
   @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();
        setIntent("This is example text");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

I already use `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and `app:showAsAction` but it still doesn't show the icon for some reason.

My project has an `appcompat.v7` dependency. 
can anyone help me please?

Comment: did you created OnOptionCreate() method in Activity ??

Comment: did you set `setHasOptionMenu(true)` in your `OnCreate()` method?

Comment: @sushildlh yes, i've created the method but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Jibbo no, i just tried to add it, but the method is not recognized

Comment: did u set toolbar to get action bar ?

Comment: @PreetikaKaur no i didn't, how do you do it ?

Comment: In your oncreate Take toolbar object and use setSupportActionBar(toolbar); then do the following things make sure your class should extend AppCompatActivity

Comment: why you using this `setIntent("This is example text");`

Comment: What do you mean it's not recognized? you have to add it in the onCreate of either an AppCompatActivity or Fragment.

Comment: @sushildlh i use that method to call another activity when i click on the action item

Comment: @Jibbo actually my activity class extends Activity, and i tried to change it to extends AppCompatActivity but the app crashes instead

Comment: @Micho thanks for the edit dude!

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add buttons etc. to the default action bar.
in onCreateOptionsMenu add the following code in order to add an item.

```
MenuItem aBarItem= menu.add(0,1,0,"Save");
    aBarItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
aBarItem.setIcon(//Drawable icon//);
```

then just add onclicklistener to this menu item to make it work.
I hope this helped

Comment: actually i prefer to do it in xml though, i'll try this at last resort, thanks